# iOS: assigning URL to variable and then opening the URL in a table view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, parsing

new to iOS.

Things work when I hardcode an argument, passing it as a string to URLWithString: like this -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://files.parse.com/81b196c3-d103-4db1-bb6f-0c74acedfa8c/5f0718e2-a79a-454c-ae9c-082ba28a74-Kontractor_test2.pdf"];
[ourApplication openURL:url];
}
```

but when I try adding an object: method and then pass a variable to URLWithString:  like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"link"];
NSString *fileURL;
fileURL = cell.textLabel.text;
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL];
[ourApplication openURL:url];
}
```

The simulator won't bring bring up the browser when I click the table cell.  Any idea why this is happening?  Thank you

Comment: if you add `NSLog(@"fileURL: %@", fileURL);` does it print out the string the same way you have it hardcoded?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint at the start of your method and walked through it, what did you see?

Answer (score 0):

The url you are passing must be not supported by the simulator (tel:, local resources, etc.).